# rails length validation exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

It is possible have in model for example user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number 
  validates_length_of :number, :is => 4
 ...
end
```

validation on length 4 (1234) with one exception that number can be value 0 ? :-)
i was looking to documentation here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html but i dont know how to do it ?

edit: now i realized that maybe regexp can be used, but thats not my strong field :-p

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you specify your question?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to allow length of zero to prepare for the case the input is nil or blank.

There is built-in simple solution for such case

```
validates :number, length { :is => 4 }, allow_blank: true
# allow_blank includes cases of both nil and blank
```

Done.

Doc: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Comment: Hello, thank you but database admin want have it 0 for some reason so i need some allow_zero: true :_)

Comment: @Muflix, tell me what number is of length 0 so you can allow that.

Comment: no length but concrete number, example: allowed numbers are [0,1111,1234,9999...] but i pushed on db admin an now its allow NULL so i can use you solution, thank you

Comment: My pleasure :) It should be nil or blank(for string, array) if the length is 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the number comes in as a string you can validate the format of it with a regex to achieve something close:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number 
  validates :number, :format => { :with => /^(\d{4}|0{1})$/ }
 ...
end
```

This says to validate the format of the number (assuming it is a string) such that from the beginning of the string there is either a pattern of 4 digits or a single 0 digit followed by the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, but number is integer, it is possible to have similar regexp for integer ?